# Turtle graphics - How to check if "ok" or "cancel" was clicked in text input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

When I use `wn.textinput()`, how do I check to see if the user clicked on the "ok" or "cancel" button? Kind of like this:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.textinput("NOTICE","Are you sure? ")
if ok was clicked: # how to do that
#do some stuff
else:
#some other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would react based on if some textinput data was supplied or not supplied *(I realize this isn't specifically if OK is clicked)*:

```py
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
response = wn.textinput("NOTICE","Are you sure? ")

if response:
    wn.bgcolor("blue")
else:
    wn.bgcolor("red")
```